# Change a single bit of a number

Tags: java, bit

Having the number `5` as `b101`, how can I change any bit of it from a certain position? Ex: `change(3)` will make it `b100`.

Comment: You can flip a bit with the XOR `^` operator.  The other operand should have only the bit to be flipped set.

Comment: Then I should generate a number with as many bits as the length of my number.

Comment: An `int` uses 32 bits, a `long` uses 64 bits, etc. regardless of the amount of non 0-padded bits required to represent it.

Comment: Also note that bits are typically numbered from least significant bit to most significant bit (right to left), and numbering starts at zero.  If I was using your API, I would expect `change(3)` to return a result of `b1101`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x` contains your number and n is the binary digit that you chant to change,

```
public int change(int x, int n) {
    return x ^ (1 << n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of backwards. First off, bits are usually counted starting with 0. They are also counted right-to-left.

So

```
Number: 1101101
Bit #:  6543210
```

Starting with b101, changing "bit 3" will change to b1101, you count from the right.

Changing bit 2 will change to b001.

If it is a simple integer, you can use the xor (`^`) operator, and shift-left (`<<`).  For example.  `5 ^ (1 << 2)` is equal to `1`.

More generally `number ^ (1 << bitNum)`. will give you the value of `number` with the bit `bitNum` reversed.

Now, if you really want to start from the left, you can use [Integer.highestOneBit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit%28int%29) like so:

`number ^ (Integer.highestOneBit(number) >> (bitNum-1));`  This will work exactly as you have in the example, though be careful when number=0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with xor masking.

You can do it the following:

```
int a = 0b101;
System.out.println(a);
int b = a ^ 0b001;
System.out.println(b);
```

Here the `a ^ 0b001` xors all bits and thus flips the least significant bit.